# How can I handle more than 2 GB RAM?

Tags: ati, lenovo, ram

I got a Lenovo g475 laptop, with a AMD e-300 processor. According to what I have read, the processor can handle up to 8GB and same the motherboard. When I was using Windows 7 starter I could handle a maximum of 2Gb because the operation system could only handle that, but here in Ubuntu 12.1(?) read some about that, and tried the `sudo dmidecode -t 16`, and it told me that I could only handle 2Gb.

How can I handle more RAM? I'm new to Ubuntu. I would like to know if the problem is in the motherboard, processor, the system or the BIOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [PAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) if you want your software to be 32-bit. But it is recommended to use 64-bit software as it has more hardware optimizations.

To use PAE, run in the Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-pae
```

then reboot. [Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingPAE).

Here are the links for Ubuntu 64-bit. Note that you should reinstall it:

- [LTS Release (12.04.4)](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?release=lts&bits=64&distro=desktop&status=zeroc)
- [Latest Release (13.10)](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?release=latest&bits=64&distro=desktop&status=zeroc)

Comment: I will  try  that, hope that works.